# How can I call a function in javascript/jquery on a variable change or position change?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to javascript. I'm quite comfortable with making apps in an object orientated SDK I use. Been looking around online for a solution to some simple things but can't seem to find an answer.

How can I call a function when a variable reaches a particular value or when an object reaches a particular co-ordinate?

In the SDK mentioned above I would simply say:

if myVariable = 10
do something

or
if object.position.y = 90
do something

Javascript doesn't seem to work that way? It seems like you can only call a function on an event like mousclick or mouseover etc? How can I call the function without using an event?

Thanks for any help!

Your replies seem to be saying I just call a function from an if statement. (Which is what I would have expected!). But every test I do does not trigger the function like in the example below the function hello does not trigger. What am I doing wrong?

```
var count = 0;

function hello()
{
    console.log("hello");
}

setInterval(function ()
{ 
   count++;
   console.log(count);
}, 2000); 

if(count==2)
{
    hello();
}
```

Comment: Your answer probably lies in the 'Events' section of this http://oscarotero.com/jquery/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling functions? That's pretty easy. You can use `functionName()` to call a function. Like this:

```
if (myVariable == 10) {
  doSomething();
}

if (object.position.y == 90) {
  moveObject(object);
}

function doSomething() {
  alert('hello!');
}

function moveObject(object) {
  object.position.y = 85;
}
```

*** EDIT: ***

Ok, based upon your code sample, the problem is that `setInterval()` executes the function without context, so the `count` variable in the surrounding code never gets changed. Also a secondary problem is that your surrounding script finishes execution before the count has risen very high, even if it was raised correctly.

You can get around this by using an intermediary function or a closure. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3MyR4/) for an example about the former.

More reading material [here](http://javascript.info/tutorial/settimeout-setinterval).

Comment: This is how I thought you could call functions. Yet every test I do, the function is not called. Example: `var count = 0;

function hello()
{
 console.log("hello");
}

setInterval(function ()
{ 
        count++;
        console.log(count);
 
}, 1000); 
    
if(count==2)
{
 hello();
}`

Comment: Edit the code into your question, comments aren't really designed for code snippets.

Comment: Edited my answer as well to reflect on the issues there.

Comment: Great thanks for your solution! I'll look at what you did and see if I can apply that to the other cases where I'd want to just trigger a function from an if statement.

Comment: Glad if it helped, just a tip for the future: post a bit of code and explain why/how it fails to show what you've done in your original question. That way it's easier for other to get a grasp what you're looking for. You get quicker answers and less downvotes. :)

Comment: Will do. Am new to stack overflow as I'm sure you guessed :) So from your fix it looks like you have to specify when an if statement is to be triggered. In the SDK I am used to they are automatically checked every frame. So they can be inserted outside of any context. Hence my confusion. So I will have to figure out how to wrap my if statements. e.g for when i want to trigger an image animation after an object has stopped moving.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (myVariable == 10 || object.prosition.y == 90){
   // do something
}
else{
   // do something else
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I understand how to write if statements. But functions do not seem to trigger from if statements alone?